# Can't echo variable from a function

Tags: php, function, url, curl, foreach

i am trying to ping URL, and if successful return URL key in the variable.
Whatever url will ping i will use it outside of the function.

```
function findUrl(){
    $links = array(
        'www.anyurl.com/ping'  => 'www.anyurl.com',
        'www-01.anyurl.com/ping' => 'www-01.anyurl.com',
        'www-02.anyurl.com/ping' => 'www-02.anyurl.com',
        'www-03.anyurl.com/ping' => 'www-03.anyurl.com'
    );
    foreach($links as $value => $key){
        $ch = curl_init($value);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){
            echo $value; // Does ehco Ping URL
            echo $key; // Does echo URL
            exit;
        } else {echo "Not successful."}
    };
    echo "didn't work" . "<br>";
}
findUrl(); // run function
echo $value; // Doesn't return URL. But i somehow need it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to `exit`, you want to `return`.  `exit` terminates the whole script.

```
return $value;
```

Then when you call the function, you need to receive the returned value:

```
$val = findUrl();
echo $val;
```